# Detect points in image and compare them

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, feature-detection

I am trying to extract points from image that makes up some sign.

[image: original picture]

First of all I am applying adaptive threshold:

[image: adaptive]

Then I try to detect blobs and ignore all that don't make up the sign with measuring distances and blobs radius.

[image: detection]

But that doesn't do it precisly (different original image) and many artefacts are detected. I tried all variations of parameters, but none fits for :

[image]

Is there some better way to it?

The picture comes from camera and I am trying to detect missing dots in sign. If dots are missing, they missing from the bottom and affect entire row (so they affect total height of sign). Now I am creating template with no missing dots and compare it to actual image every few frames, but that doesn't work, because the error that missing dots create is smaller than error between frames.

Any ideas for better approach to this problem?

Comment: Maybe you can get a higher quality image? The light source seems to reflect, and the blur doesn't help either. I think it's a difficult problem right now.

Comment: No, higher quality is impossible. Camera has 200fps and printer that prints that signs prints 200 of them, so one frame per one sign.

Comment: You can see my result. I edited of my answer and put a link to the resulting image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dealt with a similar problem, my approach was longer, but it gave more parameters to tune (a benefit as much as it can be a curse) - anyways:

1. **GaussianBlur** (if required)
2. **Canny** filter
3. **Dilate** (if required to close the 'rings' from the Canny step)
4. **findContours**

Play around with the initial image processing so that it errs on the side of giving (slightly) more candidates contours than you should - *then* filter according to the characteristics of your targets vs. false positives.

*If you haven't used contours and moment analysis before, now is the time to read up on it...*

In my case I implemented:

- A 'hierarchical' filter based on how nested the contours were within
  each other.
- A 'morphological' filter that looked for contours that had perimeter to area ratios close to what an ideal circle has (this looks relevant to your task).

Comment: A closing instead of a simple Dilate should give same results, and get a better preservation of the image.

Comment: @FiReTiTi, I hadn't heard of 'closing' before - but looking it up I read "It is obtained by the **dilation** of an image *followed* by an erosion.". This seems just as inherently destructive in terms of information as a plain dilate, if not more ... Maybe I read the wrong documentation? (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html#closing)

Comment: Also keep in mind, I'm using dilate *post* canny: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WLFUw.png

Comment: The closing will not destroy what was already present. You can convince yourself by closing a simple point. here is an example: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/close.htm

Comment: What I mean by destructive is that there is no reciprocal/inverse operation that can be *generally* applied that will result in the original image again. It's 'lossy'.

Comment: Yes, but a simple dilation will be even more destructive. Add an erosion after will reduce this effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91829/discussion-between-lamar-latrell-and-firetiti).

Comment: I used this solution, parts of it, and now I can get a little better results. For detecting missing rows of dots I just detect left-top most and right-bottom most point and comparing height between frames. Thank you for tips.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've just tested and it gives good results:

1. Opening + closing with a small structuring element radius in order to clean a little bit your image
2. Big white top hat in order to extract your text.

It gives a better result than an automatic thresholding.

[EDIT] here is a result, but with just an opening and a white top-hat of size 13: [result](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/NumberTest.png)

Comment: You should provide the code you tried and show the results

Comment: I used the plugging FastMorphology in ImageJ, with structuring elements of type square, radius 2 for step 1, and radius  23 for step 2.

Answer (score -1):

Result

[image]I have implemented the code as per the direction @FiReTiTi. Please check out.!!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    Mat src = imread("7.png",1);
    imshow("src",src);
    src = src + Scalar (75,75,75);
    Mat erosion_dst;
    Mat dilation_dst;
    Mat dilation_dst1;
    int erosion_size = 8;   
cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS,
                      cv::Size(2 * erosion_size + 1, 2 * erosion_size + 1), 
                      cv::Point(erosion_size, erosion_size) );
    erode( src, erosion_dst, element );
    erode(  erosion_dst, erosion_dst, element );
    erode(  erosion_dst, erosion_dst, element );
    dilate(erosion_dst, dilation_dst1, element );

    dilate(dilation_dst1, dilation_dst, element );
    dilate(dilation_dst, dilation_dst, element );
    dilate(dilation_dst, dilation_dst, element );
    erode( dilation_dst, dilation_dst, element );

    imshow("opening of image",dilation_dst);

    Mat topHat= src-dilation_dst;
    //topHat = topHat + 255;
    imshow("tophat image",topHat);

for(int i=0;i<topHat.rows;i++)
 {
  for(int j=0;j<topHat.cols;j++)
  {
   if(topHat.at<uchar>(i,j) > 2 )
    {
     //originalImage.at<Vec3b>(i,j) = 255;
        topHat.at<uchar>(i,j)=255;

        //   cout << i<<" " <<j<< endl; 
     }
   }
 }
//

imshow("Final image",topHat);
    waitKey();
}
```

Comment: I don't know opencv, but your succession of erode / dilate is really weird, and the top-hat is even weirder. You should not have to use loops in order to perform a top-hat.

Comment: @FiReTiTi Hello sir, 1. i didn't use a loop to perform Top-Hat. 2. Tophat = Original Image-  Opening transformation image.

Comment: I have just used the loop to raise the pixel value to 255. Please run this code and check out.

Comment: Ok, my bad. But I am still very surprised by the triple erosion/dilation

Comment: To my bad luck the inner statement of the for loop didn't work for me.!!